# Copy N number of bytes from a location

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to copy 8 bytes from a memory location. I am getting all zeroes instead of 5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E.

```
typedef struct {

    uint8_t id[8];
}pid_local_t;

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[256];
    uint8_t i = 0;
    pid_local_t val;
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    printf(" val 0x%08x \n",*(uint32_t*)(arr+5));
    memcpy(arr+5,&val,8);
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
       printf(" val %d => 0x%08x \n",i,val.id[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
 val 0x08070605 
 val 0 => 0x00 
 val 1 => 0x00 
 val 2 => 0x00 
 val 3 => 0x00 
 val 4 => 0x00 
 val 5 => 0x00 
 val 6 => 0x00 
 val 7 => 0x00
```

Comment: `*(uint32_t*)(arr+5)` results in undefined behavior by breaking the strict aliasing rules, just so you know.

Comment: The arguments to `memcpy` are destination, source, length, in that order. So the code is not putting anything into `val`.

Comment: also be aware that `arr[255]` will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `memcpy` copies in wrong direction.

It should be:

```
memcpy(&val,arr+5,sizeof(val));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/as6xxo

Comment: I’d prefer to see `val.id` instead of `&val`, though both work.

Comment: it is single member struct. There is no need to get the address of the member